# Radgrid: Change extracted values on update command for automatic updates

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

On a regular formview against an objectDataSource, we define the method for the Updating event to add values to the item that is being edited, something like this:

```
protected void MyFormView_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{        
    RadComboBox countriesCombo =
        (RadComboBox)MyFormView.FindControl("CountryRadComboBox");
    // this should never be null, other wise, error is shown
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countriesCombo.SelectedValue))
        e.NewValues["CountryId"] = countriesCombo.SelectedValue;
```

In a RadGrid, I am using an edit form. Insert is working great putting this code in the PerformInsert event method:

```
GridEditFormInsertItem gridItem = (GridEditFormInsertItem)e.Item.OwnerTableView.GetInsertItem();

Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
gridItem.ExtractValues(values);
values["ReferenceId"] = 0;
RadComboBox comboCountries = (RadComboBox)gridItem.FindControl("CountryRadComboBox");
values["CountryID"] = comboCountries.SelectedValue;                
e.Item.OwnerTableView.InsertItem(values);
```

However, trying to do the same for edit is not working for me. It is the last step that I am not being able to do. Once I change the hashtable values with the value in the combo, how do I indicate that it has to use these values?

In the telerik examples they work it out with a DataTable obtained from the datasource and then mapping and doing the update in the code.... don't wanna do that, i would love it would work the same way the insert does. For the case when i dont need to change any value in the hashtable it works perfectly, the update is working.

Any help appreciated
Vladimir

Comment: I'm assuming you're using their automagic update, with a `SqlDataSource` control on the page?

Comment: I am using an ObjectDataSource that has the InsertMethod, UpdateMethod, DeleteMethod and SelectMethod well declared. This objectdatasource is the datasource for my RadGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the extracted values should already be set to the selected value of the dropdown. Try using `Bind` to set the selected value in the markup:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlCountries" runat="server" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CountryID") %>' ...>
```

Comment: Well, first, the selectedValue property does not appear on the valid properties for RadComboBox in my case (i tried to put it anyways and it does not work). But, assuming this is another issue for me and radcombobox, how can i do this for complex components and/or situations where i need the behavior as described in the question?

Comment: Intellisense doesn't pick it up, but it is there. I've used it many times. Not sure why it didn't work when you tried, but it should if done correctly. Have you tried using **Bind** and **Eval**? What kind of datasource are you using, and can you elaborate on what you meant by behavior?